# No dual-boot menu after installing Ubuntu. Windows10 and Ubuntu on different drives

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, windows-10, 16.10

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.10 on my HDD and used the "install alongside" option so I can choose to boot up Windows 10 off the SSD or Ubuntu off the HDD upon startup. After installing, Ubuntu said I needed to restart my system, so I did. But now I'm running into the issue of no dual-boot menu popping up, so I can't choose Ubuntu and it goes straight to Windows10.

Windows10 uses a EFI for startup, so my system is set to UEFI. I'm not sure if this is creating an issue or not. Windows EFI and primary partition are on the SSD. Ubuntu EFI and primary partitions are on the HDD. Any help would be much appreciated.

**SOLVED** sorta. After Ubuntu installed and restarted, I went into the UEFI settings on startup and applied a supervisor password. This grants you access to a lot of tools and options that were inaccessible. From there I enabled the "open boot menu with f12" option. Also, I added a trusted EFI partition, which had the Ubuntu GRUB option. Now, if I press f12 upon startup, it takes me to a boot manager and I can choose between the windows boot manager or the GRUB. If i don't press F12, it goes straight to Windows10

Comment: Does the GRUB menu appear if you hold down the **LEFT SHIFT** key during boot up? Cheers, Al

Answer (score 1):

In the BIOS change the boot priority to the drive with Ubuntu first. It should then boot to Ubuntu and show the grub menu. If it boots to Ubuntu but does not show the grub menu on startup run the following command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

This will update grub to include windows 10, provided there are not any other problems.

Comment: So I tried that method, but even with the HDD set to boot first, Windows10 still loads up. I did find a solution to my problem though, I'll edit into my original question.

Comment: That is interesting. I have a very similar setup. I have windows 10 on one ssd and ubuntu on another. I have the boot priority setup to boot off the ssd with ubuntu and the grub menu has an entry for windows 10 and ubuntu, which is what I think you want (you don't have to press f12). When I installed everything I took out one ssd and installed windows 10, then removed the windows 10 ssd and inserted the other ssd and installed ubuntu. (so they wouldn't interfere with each other.) Then I ran "sudo update-grub" in ubuntu and now the grub menus has ubuntu and windows 10. make sure to use UEFI